# More efficient way of Deserializing JSON string to 1 of 2 object types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have data stored in a DB field acting as a cache from an API call. 
This data is either of the type:

- `MyObject`
- `List<MyObject>`

I currently have the following code which uses `NewtonSoft.JSON` to take the string and (based on a successful deserialization) determine which of those types the string is.

```
var _lstObj = new List<MyObject>();
var _obj = new MyObject();
bool isList = false;

try
{
    var n = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(cacheString);
    if(n!=null && n.Count()>0)
    {
        _lstObj = n;
        isList = true;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    isList = false;
}


if (!isList)
{
    try 
    {
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(cacheString);
        if (x != null && x.Data != null)
        {
            _obj = x;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

This feels kind of cumbersome...is there a better way to do this?

I'll always have a string for the incoming data.

It will only ever be 1 of those 2 types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var obj = (JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cacheString);
if (obj.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    var result = obj.ToObject<List<MyObject>>();
}
else
{
    var result = obj.ToObject<MyObject>();
}
```

Comment: Nice. I like the look of that. I’ll give it a go

Comment: Could replace `(JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cacheString)` with `JToken.Parse(cacheString)`

Answer (score 3):

Checking first if the json string is a list should solve the problem.

```cs
if (cacheString.StartsWith("["))
{
    var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(cacheString);
}
else
{
    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(cacheString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the expando object, that way you can keep adding properties if you like dynamically.

```
        dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject();

        try
        {
            exp.isList = true;
            exp.value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(cacheString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exp.isList = false;
            exp.value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(cacheString);
        }
```

**but ideally I would cache the object as a List regardless if its one or many.**